# What does the parentheses mean in vector calculus?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

What does $\vec{a}(\vec{b} + \vec{c}) means?$ Is it $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}+\vec{a}\cdot\vec{c}$ or is it the cross product $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\vec{a}\times\vec{c}$?

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't have a standard meaning.  You'll have to guess based on context.

Comment: I've never encountered the case where parentheses stand for the cross product. I would write the second case as $\vec a \times(\vec b+\vec c)$

Comment: Do you have a reference that uses this notation?

Comment: I've seen that in a question like 'is this expression defined?" with the answer being "no". And I've seen that in Geometric Algebra/Clifford Algebras. What is your context?

Comment: Could you add a link to the  cited text? Or an image? Please ensure to include the preceding and subsequent few lines for sake of context.

Comment: As you can guess from the previous comments, what it means is somebody made a typo. Parentheses mean the same thing for vectors that they mean elsewhere: grouping to indicate priority of operations. What is wrong here is that there is no operation on vectors that is commonly denoted by juxtaposition. Thus whoever wrote this out made a mistake, dropping the dot product or cross product operator that should have been included. With some context we could probably figure out what they meant, but with just the expression itself, we cannot.

Comment: @insipidintegrator https://imgur.com/a/joVC5Hq I saw it on this integral From Raily and Hobson's Mathematical Methods book. It's from the vector calculus chapter. I know how this integral is solved but I was just wondering what would it mean to expand the parentheses.

Comment: @MarkS. https://imgur.com/a/joVC5Hq

Comment: The thing inside is a dot product, meaning it is scalar. It is not a vector. So no confusion!

Comment: So it always depends on the context?

Comment: @insipidintegrator I think you could expand that into an answer (and user1070087 could type what the image shows into the question; it's much different from $\vec a(\vec b+\vec c)$!)

Comment: @user1070087 Yes it depends on context.

Comment: @MarkS. : done.

Comment: @MarkS. I was just curious about the general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image that the OP shares with us basically contains the expression $$\int [\vec a(\dot{\vec b}\cdot \vec a+\vec b\cdot\dot{\vec a})+\dot{\vec a}(\vec b\cdot\vec a)-2(\dot{\vec a}\cdot\vec a)\vec b-\dot{\vec b}|\vec a|^2]\ dt$$

All of the expressions inside the parentheses are dot products or scalar products of two vectors, which gives us a scalar in the parentheses. Thus, we are just multiplying a vector with a scalar here.

The dot or cross products will ***always*** be written as $\vec a\cdot(\vec b+\vec c)$ or $\vec a\times (\vec b+\vec c)$ respectively.